# Showing interdependency of items in backlog

Tags: jira, process, backlog, task-management, sprint-backlog

In cases where we have two stories dependent on the same task, is there a way to show the dependency besides adding a comment in the stories? Additionally, in cases with multiple dependencies that are being blocked, is there a way to make things visible without going over the comments ticket by a ticket?

Answer (score 2):

There's a "Link issue" button on the Jira issue screen:

[image]

When you click on it, it will show the "relates to" section. There, you will have some labels to tag the relation:

[image]

Comment: It might be worth adding that there are some plugins that allow you to visualise the links, like SpiderView and Dependency Mapper.